# URL Shortener Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

well I've got a URL shortener, http://shrt.in/ and I thought of having a bookmarklet feature for it.

I've got one already, I haven't put it up on my site though, because I need to make it better.

Here's the one I have now :

```
javascript:location.href='http://shrt.in/shrt.php?long='+encodeURIComponent(location)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title);
```

You click the bookmarklet while you're on the website that you want to be shortened, then it will redirect you to my website, where you can copy the URL.

I was wondering if I could somehow shorten the URL, and paste it in the address bar without having to redirect to my website.

So you go to the website with a long URL, click the bookmarklet, and the address bar is changed with the new shortened URL.

I know this can be done because I used to use a URL shortener a couple of years ago that had this feature, but unfortunately, the owner gave up on it and it died.

This will be a really great help for me, and I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me out.

Comment: JavaScript would not usually have the ability to modify the URL bar. This would be a big security problem if the user did not explicitly request it, as they would for an addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it! all you need is an listener on shrt.in which will accept url to shorten and return a shortned url, you need to pass the long url via cross site ajax and get the result from your site, instead of redirecting to your site and then doing the shorting.

hope it helps.

Comment: i said cross site ajax, keeping in mind that the shrt.in is a seperate site and it is called from a different website.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for answering. Could you please explain more how this works? I'm not a really experienced coder. My first project was this URL Shortener.

Comment: oh! i would request you to go through jquery ajax and how to make ajax calls, that will help you with the same! say you have shrt.php?q=url which will shorten your url in the ajax call you would pass the q= parameter as the long url, your shrt.php should shorten and return the shorten url ... let me know if it helps with a rep

Comment: if you feel my answer helped you! help me with a rep!

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to give rep?

Comment: Click on the uparrow :) next to my answer .. you should probably post a new item on the same :)

Answer (score 0):

if i am getting you right you need to pass parameter with your shorten url for ur original url

below link may help you out for this https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/url-shortener-that-supports-parameters

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't mean that. If you read carefully, I have a bookmarklet, that takes the URL of a page, shortens it, and redirects to my website and you can copy the shortened URL. But I don't want it to redirect to my website. I want it to shorten the link, then paste it in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `http://shrt.in/` so that instead of just displaying the shortened link, you redirect right away to the shortened link.

It seems that SHRT.IN is using PHP. Edit the `shrt.php` file so that you can redirect the user.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I need. I don't want it to redirect straight to the shortened URL. Because most of the users that use my service shorten the URLs so they can copy it and share if via social networking sites, forums, blogs etc... That's why I need it to return the shorten URL to the address bar. Thanks for answering though.